# ASP.NET MVC : problem Including libraries in views with conditional

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am working on a map manager that changes according to a certain condition (switch between OpenLayers and Google Maps). I have almost all the work done, I just need to load certain libraries based on that configuration. The problem is that with Open Layers it seems not to load the libraries correctly, since it does not show the map at all.

Attached screenshots and the code I use:

Open Layers:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvhPA.png)

Google Maps:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u0YgP.png)

Code:

```
@if (enviroments.UsarOpenLayers)
{
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.4.0/dist/ol.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Viglino/ol-ext/master/dist/ol-ext.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/ol@v7.4.0/ol.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/Viglino/ol-ext/master/dist/ol-ext.min.css">
}
else
{
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=keyEx" async defer></script>
}
```

PS: yes, I have verified if the conditional is fulfilled and it does.

Comment: we need a fully reproducible example. the code you provided is out of context and not helpful.  we need to able to reproduce the issue